# Printing live calculated values onto main window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, kinect-interaction

I am writing an application in Visual Studio 2013 using C#

I have some live values that I get from Kinect and I process those values and save them in a floating point.

there are about 8 values

I need to print these values out on my window 
how do I go about that??

Comment: Can you enter you floating point values

Comment: @Jamshed those values are constantly changing because the person in front of kinect is moving. it just need my user to be able to see what the angles are for the body of the person in front of the sensor

Comment: You are going to show points in some List like text or point on Window?

Comment: i'd like to do that yes. with proper labels

Comment: @JamshedAkhmedov do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to Display your constantly changing floating point number on your Window, You can use `Label` . But as values changing frequently this may cause GUI  to hang. To prevent this I have an extension Class

```
public static class CrossThreadExtensions
{
    public static void PerformSafely(this Control target, Action action)
    {
        if (target.InvokeRequired)
        {
            target.Invoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }

    public static void PerformSafely<T1>(this Control target, Action<T1> action, T1 parameter)
    {
        if (target.InvokeRequired)
        {
            target.Invoke(action, parameter);
        }
        else
        {
            action(parameter);
        }
    }

    public static void PerformSafely<T1, T2>(this Control target, Action<T1, T2> action, T1 p1, T2 p2)
    {
        if (target.InvokeRequired)
        {
            target.Invoke(action, p1, p2);
        }
        else
        {
            action(p1, p2);
        }
    }
}
```

And use in this way

On value change event:

```
Thread erThread = new Thread(delegate()
{
    label1.PerformSafely(() => label1.Text = _YourFloatingPointValue.ToString());
});
erThread.Start();
erThread.IsBackground = true;
```

Comment: Thank you I am going to give it a try